# Activeadmin with activeadmin-axlsx gem, getting bin/rails:6: warning: already initialized constant APP_PATH Error

Tags: excel, activeadmin, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I'm using **ActiveAdmin** gem for Admin Interface in my **Rails4.1** application, I want to download the index page in excel sheet, for that i have used **activeadmin-axlsx gem** to get download xlsx files. After adding this gem into my Gemfile, running **rails s** getting the below error in development mode.

> bin/rails:6: warning: already initialized constant APP_PATH

i have tried the below code also,

```
rake rails:update:bin
```

not able to start the server.

How do i solve this error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added the below gem in Gemfile

```
gem 'zip-zip'
```

rails s is working fine.

Comment: Thanks. This worked for acts_as_xlsx under Rails 4.2.4 a well.